# Shed door too heavy for hinges

Tags: shed, hinges

Someone kindly made these wooden doors for our garage, but the hinges keep breaking. Right door is only hanging by the middle hinge. It seems the doors are too heavy for them.

Can anyone suggest a better arrangement (more hinges, longer or stronger hinges)? Or is there any way I can reduce the weight by adding something like a spring or bunjee cord attached to the roof. I don't really care how it looks. There's not much room in the frame, for the other end of the hinges to attach to... Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When the hinges were put on, was there any binding/hard to open/close of the doors?   If you use a string with a weight(a plumb bob), would all hinge pins be inline from top to bottom?

Comment: The door has been problematic for quite a while, maybe with the wood expanding due to snow. rain etc. I think they might have been in line once, but not now :-)

Comment: I'd start with trying to shim them to actually be in line. If they aren't coaxial (lined up) that puts *tremendous* force on the hinge when you operate the door.  And the door binds also!

Comment: Thanks for your answers... That is true the door is 'fighting' with the frame right now.. Will try to line them up  using the plumb line

Answer (score 7):

Gate hinges would be a common heavy duty hinge that's usually easy to find. We're talking "farm supply or similar" as in "agricultural gate 10-16 foot wide" not 3 foot gate in a picket fence.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try to find those.. I was also looking at maybe some kind of caster at the opening to reduce the weight on the hinge side... something with the ability to go over uneven surface. It might be tricky to install but will give both of those a try...

Comment: Try **spring loaded gate wheel** in your search engine of choice. Either that, or make a level track for the wheel in front of the door. You'll want a large diameter wheel if the ground is rough, bumpy and uneven.